# How do I manually multiply and add to a 128-bit number by a 64-bit number

Tags: c

I have a 128-bit uint stored as two 64-bit uints and I need to add and multiply the latter to the former but I'm not really sure how to get started on this. Do I need to break the 128-bit number up into four 32-bit numbers and the 64-bit number into two 32-bit numbers or is there a quicker way to do this?

```
void                                                                            
_add(                                                                           
    uint64_t x[2],                                                                
    uint64_t y                                                                    
) {          
    x[0] += y;
    x[1] = ?                                
}     

void                                                                            
_multiply(                                                                      
    uint64_t x[2],                                                                
    uint64_t y                                                                    
) {          
    x[0] *= y;
    x[1] = ?                                                       
}
```

Comment: What size product: 192, 128, or ???

Comment: "Do I need to break the 128-bit number up into four 32-bit numbers and the 64-bit number into two 32-bit numbers " --> is a very likely 1st step then do 4*2 multiplies, then add.

Comment: "manually"?  I'd definitely get a computer to do that.

Comment: It'll be a little quicker to start with `x` and `y` as arrays of `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 1):

For addition, we need to simulate the carry between chunks. A carry exists if the sum is smaller than either of the two addends. Based on this, we can formulate three macros `ADDcc` for add with carry-out, `ADDC` for add with carry-in, and `ADDCcc` for add with carry-pin and carry-out. Here we are dealing with just two chunks, so need only `ADDcc` and `ADDC`. In addition to the carry variable, these macros need two temporary variables for internal use.

For the multiply, we need the capability to generate the more significant (high) half of a full double-width product. Where no machine-specific intrinsics and no wider integer type than `uint64_t` are available, this can easily be accomplished by splitting each 64-bit factor into two 32-bit halves, and compositing the result from four partial products of these halves.

```c
#define ADDcc(a,b,cy,t0,t1) (t0=(b), t1=(a), t0=t0+t1, cy=t0<t1, t0=t0)
#define ADDC(a,b,cy,t0,t1) (t0=(b)+cy, t1=(a), t0+t1)
#define ADDCcc(a,b,cy,t0,t1) (t0=(b)+cy, t1=(a), cy=t0<cy, t0=t0+t1, t1=t0<t1, cy=cy+t1, t0=t0)

uint64_t umul64hi (uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    uint64_t a_lo = (uint64_t)(uint32_t)a;
    uint64_t a_hi = a >> 32;
    uint64_t b_lo = (uint64_t)(uint32_t)b;
    uint64_t b_hi = b >> 32;
    uint64_t p0 = a_lo * b_lo;
    uint64_t p1 = a_lo * b_hi;
    uint64_t p2 = a_hi * b_lo;
    uint64_t p3 = a_hi * b_hi;
    uint32_t cy = (uint32_t)(((p0 >> 32) + (uint32_t)p1 + (uint32_t)p2) >> 32);
    return p3 + (p1 >> 32) + (p2 >> 32) + cy;
}

void _add (uint64_t x[2], uint64_t y) 
{
    uint64_t cy, t0, t1;          
    x[0] = ADDcc (x[0], y, cy, t0, t1);
    x[1] = ADDC (x[1], 0, cy, t0, t1);                 
}

void _multiply (uint64_t x[2], uint64_t y) 
{
    x[1] = umul64hi (x[0], y) + x[1] * y;           
    x[0] = x[0] * y;                                            
}
```